# Maximal value of the Boost Multiprecision type 'float128' gives me a compilation error with GCC in C++20 mode

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, c++20, boost-multiprecision

This simple code can't be compiled with the `-std=c++20` option:

```
#include <limits>
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>

namespace bm = boost::multiprecision;

int main()
{
  auto const m = std::numeric_limits<bm::float128>::max();
}
```

The compilation command and its error output:

```
hekto@ubuntu:~$ g++ -std=c++20 test.cpp
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static std::numeric_limits<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::float128_backend, ExpressionTemplates> >::number_type std::numeric_limits<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::float128_backend, ExpressionTemplates> >::max() [with boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option ExpressionTemplates = boost::multiprecision::et_off; std::numeric_limits<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::float128_backend, ExpressionTemplates> >::number_type = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::float128_backend, boost::multiprecision::et_off>]’:
test.cpp:8:53:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp:728:55: error: could not convert ‘boost::multiprecision::quad_constants::quad_max’ from ‘const __float128’ to ‘std::numeric_limits<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::float128_backend, boost::multiprecision::et_off> >::number_type’ {aka ‘boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::float128_backend, boost::multiprecision::et_off>’}
  728 |    static number_type (max)() BOOST_NOEXCEPT { return BOOST_MP_QUAD_MAX; }
      |                                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                       |
      |                                                       const __float128
```

Why is that?

- OS: Xubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- Compiler: g++ (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0
- Boost: 1.71.0

Comment: Is that the *only* message in the full and complete build log? What is the *exact* message? Please show us exactly how you build (full command with all options and flags), the full and complete build log output, and what version of Boost you have installed.

Comment: Replicates - live - https://godbolt.org/z/WhanYK8fe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/float128.html) states:

> When compiling with gcc, you need to use the flag --std=gnu++11/14/17, as the suffix 'Q' is a GNU extension. Compilation fails with the flag --std=c++11/14/17 unless you also use -fext-numeric-literals.

So you need to specify `--std=gnu++20` instead of `--std=c++20`. The boost documentation is not up-to-date. [The flag enables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) various [GNU extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html), one of it being [`__float128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html).

See [example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7zWsqhzhd).

The underlying reason for the compiler error is that without the `--std=gnu++17` or `--std=gnu++20` flag, `_GLIBCXX_USE_FLOAT128` is not defined, meaning [`BOOST_HAS_FLOAT128`](https://github.com/boostorg/config/blob/eb3a0a98ae53ec1b35d8e94c912386e736a2ae39/include/boost/config/compiler/gcc.hpp#L170) is not defined, meaning `__float128` is [not recognized as `number_kind_floating_point`](https://github.com/boostorg/multiprecision/blob/a4cd4ffe2f4c008e0fb2cdeeae1ff2a8c62efe51/include/boost/multiprecision/detail/number_base.hpp#L1593) (but as `number_kind_unknown`).
This means that `boost::multiprecision::number` [cannot be implicitly constructed](https://github.com/boostorg/multiprecision/blob/a4cd4ffe2f4c008e0fb2cdeeae1ff2a8c62efe51/include/boost/multiprecision/number.hpp#L68) from a `__float128` because [`is_restricted_conversion<__float128, boost::multiprecision::float128_backend>::value`](https://github.com/boostorg/multiprecision/blob/a4cd4ffe2f4c008e0fb2cdeeae1ff2a8c62efe51/include/boost/multiprecision/traits/is_restricted_conversion.hpp#L36) is `true` because [`bm::detail::is_lossy_conversion<__float128, boost::multiprecision::float128_backend>::value`](https://github.com/boostorg/multiprecision/blob/a4cd4ffe2f4c008e0fb2cdeeae1ff2a8c62efe51/include/boost/multiprecision/traits/is_restricted_conversion.hpp#L16) is `true`, because `__float128` is `number_kind_unknown` instead of `number_kind_floating_point`.

I.e. in short, without `gnu++20`, the `boost::multiprecision::float128` type is not supported.

Comment: s/is broken/is not supported/, but fine explanation otherwise, +1

Comment: The flag `-std=gnu++11/14/17/20` helped, but the flag`-fext-numeric-literals` did not, so it looks like the documentation needs some corrections... thank you!

Comment: Well, `-fext-numeric-literals` enables the Q suffix but does not define `_GLIBCXX_USE_FLOAT128`. Which then causes the described problems. So yes, the boost documentation is wrong to say that `-fext-numeric-literals` is sufficient.

Comment: The problem here looks even more deep - the GCC with option `-std=gnu++17` couldn't **link** my code with the `std::cout << std::numeric_limits<bm::float128>::max()` statement. The `quadmath_snprintf` function wasn't found

Comment: Once again from the [boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/float128.html): `You will need to link to libquadmath.dll with the link command -lquadmath and ensure that the DLL is visible by the linker. If you are using the B2/bjam build system then commands<linkflags>-lQUADMATH and <linkflags>-L"path/to/lib" will be needed.`

Answer (score 3):

Directly from [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/float128.html):

> When compiling with gcc, you need to use the flag `--std=gnu++11`/`14`/`17`, as the suffix `Q` is a GNU extension. Compilation fails with the flag `--std=c++11`/`14`/`17` unless you also use `-fext-numeric-literals`.

The same applies for `c++20`/`gnu++20`, the docs merely haven't yet been updated for that revision.